# Spring security provide multiple authentication mechanisms

Tags: authentication, spring-security

My RESTful webapplication needs to support multiple authentication mechanisms.
Which mechanism should be applied is not indicated by a specific URL but by using the client application name in a custom header field.
Each client application maps to a specific authentication mechanism.

Currently, we need to support the following:

- Username / password authentication
- LDAP auhtentication
- OAuth2

We defined multiple authentication providers in the our `spring-security.xml`:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="daoAuthProvider" />
    <authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider" />
    <authentication-provider ref="oAuth2Provider" />
</authentication-manager>
```

The problem is that the `AuthenticationManager` takes the first provider, tries to authenticate and executes the following provider in the chain when authentication fails.
But we 're fully aware which provider should be executed by our custom header field.
We could create a custom `Authentication` provider but this class doen't have a HttpServletRequest notion. So we're not able to read our custom header field and delegate to some provider accordingly.

Is there any other alternative to execute a specific provider based on a header field?

Comment: You should distinguish between *authentication entry point* and *authentication provider*. What you probably want is to use a specific entry point based on HTTP header. Authentication providers tend to be independent from HTTP request lifecycle. Btw. what is the difference between *LDAP authentication* and *username/password authentication*?

Comment: Btw. you can get to the native request object anywhere in your code within the request thread if you use `RequestContextListener`. See JavaDoc for `RequestContextListener`, `RequestContextHolder` and `ServletRequestAttributes`.

Comment: Is there any way I can 'map' an entry point to an authentication provider? The username/password authentication is meant for a local DB, ldap authentication makes a connection to an external ldap service.